# cast object with a Type variable

Tags: c#, types

The following doesn't work, of course. Is there a possible way, which is pretty similar like this?

```
Type newObjectType = typeof(MyClass);

var newObject = givenObject as newObjectType;
```

Comment: Have you looked into generics? `MyClass<T>`, and then `var newObject = givenObject as T`.

Comment: I've used generics for the common objects. But there are special ones which need to be casted explicitly - besides the generic ones.

Comment: What you mean by special objects?

Comment: Objects was probably the wrong word. We've got lots of custom DataFields (string, int, DateTime, ...). But there are also some we couldn't handle with generics, because there handling wasn't relative enought to the handling of integers and strings.

Comment: What is the intent?  Do you want to treat the given object as a MyClass? If so, why not just *var newObject = givenObject as MyClass*.  If not, then what is the type of newObject? How are you going to access its members?  What am I missing?  if you know the type at compile time then you should be able to cast as that type.  If you do not know the type at compile time, how are you planning to access the object?

Comment: Answering your question would be like explaining you our whole project. The structure of our data fields is very special. Some data fields are lists and needed to be treat in an other way. The value type we want to set is of the type T. If T is just an integer it's easy (handled with a generic method where the value is just set to the value). But if the value is a complex object we need to assign it in another way. I could imagine that this answer is not really satisfying(? - sorry, German :-P). But there are no more characters left. :)

Comment: Hmmm.  If the types are only known at runtime then the *as* statement will not be of use.  AFAIK it cannot have a variable on the right-hand side.

Comment: Can you expand the example a bit more.  For example, what is the intended type of newObject?  What are you intending to do?  You mention assign them but are they immutable (just replace the existing object with the new one) or do you want to update values in the existing object from the new one?

Comment: For example if we want to set the Value property of a DataField. DataFieldInt and DataFieldString are alright. DataFieldLongString (RichText) can't just be treated with the String and Int in a generic class because the method names are almost the same, but the logic behind these differs too much. Same with DataFieldDocument (binaryFile in DB). And complex DataFieldMasters (too complicated to explain). I think this confuses you even more. But yeah, I would need about 20 comments to explain that. And I'm not gonna dive further into that from now on, my question is answered, sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`newObjectType` is an **instance** of the `Type` class (containing metadata about the type) not the *type* itself.

This should work

```
var newObject = givenObject as MyClass;
```

OR

```
var newObject = (MyClass) givenObject;
```

Casting to an instance of a type really does not make sense since **compile time** has to know what the variable type should be while instance of a type is a **runtime** concept.

The only way `var` can work is that the type of the variable is known at compile-time.

---

## UPDATE

Casting generally is a compile-time concept, i.e. you have to know the type at compile-time.

Type Conversion is a runtime concept.

---

## UPDATE 2

If you need to make a call using a variable of the type and you do not know the type at compile time, you can use **reflection**: use `Invoke` method of the `MethodInfo` on the type instance.

```
object myString = "Ali";
Type type = myString.GetType();
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethods().Where(m=>m.Name == "ToUpper").First();
object invoked = methodInfo.Invoke(myString, null);
Console.WriteLine(invoked);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I think the OP wants some kind of dynamic casting at runtime.

Comment: Then that is a different problem. Also to cast to do what? **Casting is a compile time concept.**

Comment: "newObjectType is an instance of the type not the type itself" When you say "the type", are you referring to `MyClass`? Because that's not true at all.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that type-safety thing I've heard of in .NET :-D
I've tried `givenField = givenField as NewType` and I wondered that this givenField still lacks of a field which is just given in `NewType`, afterwards. But your answer gave me the clue. Sorry.^^

Comment: @sepp2k yes that is what I mean. I have updated to clarify more.

Comment: @Aliostad Agree. but as the OP asked "with a Type variable", I was under the impression he wanted run-time behavior.

Comment: @ken2k yes but in runtime casting does not make sense. You can use reflection to use the object you have only the type information.

Comment: My problem just was that I've casted a variable in a switch statement and declared it before that, that I'm still able to use it **after** the switch statement. The solution was the dynamic keyword.

Comment: @Aliostad: this kind of reflection would be much more complicated way for my issue. Wasn't the `dynamic` keyword introduced to avoid these complicated reflection stuff? Don't kill me if I'm wrong.

@H27studio: The `as` method is just for reference types. If the cast isn't successfull the object is just null. If you cast it like `(MyType)object` an exception is thrown if it's not successful.

Comment: @ebeeb true, and yes, you have to check for null, but using an if is a lighter way of control flow, much better than try catch blocks. Also, the point of good OOP is not to be passing around objects without knowing the type. There are dynamic languages for that. And probably is just a design error to do it this way. It can be done, but probably is not a good idea. Are you sure you REALLY have to do it this way?

Comment: Now that you tell me about that: I'm not sure. Probably I'm gonna implement your solution.

Comment: This answer needs to be edited or deleted. Showing how to call `MethodInfo.Invoke` still doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 9):

You can check if the type is present with IsAssignableFrom

```
if(givenObject.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(newObjectType))
```

But you can't use var here because type isn't known at compile time.

Answer (score 6):

I recently had the case, that I needed to *generate* some code like in [Tomislav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379550/tomislav-markovski). Unfortunately during generation time the type T was unknown. However, a variable containing an instance of that type was known. A <strike>solution</strike> dirty hack/ workaround for that problem would be:

```
public void CastToMyType<T>(T hackToInferNeededType, object givenObject) where T : class
{
   var newObject = givenObject as T;
}
```

Then this can be called by `CastToMyType(instanceOfNeededType, givenObject)` and let the compiler infer T.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Convert.ChangeType. According to [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=netframework-4.8), it

> returns an object of a specified type whose value is equivalent to a
>   specified object.

You could try the code below:

```
Type newObjectType = typeof(MyClass);

var newObject = Convert.ChangeType(givenObject, newObjectType);
```

Comment: Except `newObjectType` must implement the `IConvertible` interface. Otherwise, it throws `System.InvalidCastException`.

Comment: Since this returns object it will then be unable to be used as an input to some method.. which returns us back to the how to dynamically cast problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can solve this using generics.

```
public void CastToMyType<T>(object givenObject) where T : class
{
   var newObject = givenObject as T;
}
```

Comment: Nope:The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint

Comment: public void CastToMyType<T>(object givenObject) where T : class
{
   var newObject = givenObject as T;
}

Comment: With this you still have the same problem when you want to call `CastToMyType()` with a type retrieved at runtime. You are essentially trying to do this: `CastToMyType<someVar.GetType()>()` which is not possible.