# Cleaner way to instantiate different derived classes based on collection size?

Tags: c#, refactoring

Ive been trying to make a flexible method where it will fill a single collection with different derived objects. I want this method to also expand its capability based on a collection of types. Problem is, for it to look super, I need to replace an explicit cast class name with a type. I read [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005427/cast-object-with-a-type-variable) that it is not possible to cast using a class name not known at compile time.

My question to you is how would you go about refactoring this code to make it less repeating and be flexible based on collection size?

```
public struct POSSIBLE_OUTPUTS
{        
    public static Type MarekType { get; private set; }
    public static Type HawkingType { get; private set; }
    public static Type GLADOSType { get; private set; }
    public static List <Type> AllOptions { get; private set; }

    static POSSIBLE_OUTPUTS()
    {
        MarekType = typeof (MarekVoice);
        HawkingType = typeof (HawkingVoice);
        GLADOSType = typeof (GLADOSVoice);
        AllOptions = new List <Type>();
        AllOptions.Add (MarekType);
        AllOptions.Add (HawkingType);
        AllOptions.Add (GLADOSType);
    }
} 

Speeches = new List <SentenceFactory>();

for (int i = 0; i < POSSIBLE_OUTPUTS.AllOptions.Count; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < TOTAL_SPEECHES; k++)
    {     
        if (POSSIBLE_OUTPUTS.AllOptions[i] == POSSIBLE_OUTPUTS.MarekType)
        {
            Speeches.Add (Activator.CreateInstance (POSSIBLE_OUTPUTS.AllOptions[i]) as MarekVoice);                                       
        }

        else if (POSSIBLE_OUTPUTS.AllOptions[i] == POSSIBLE_OUTPUTS.HawkingType)
        {
            Speeches.Add (Activator.CreateInstance (POSSIBLE_OUTPUTS.AllOptions[i]) as HawkingVoice);                                       
        }

        else if (POSSIBLE_OUTPUTS.AllOptions[i] == POSSIBLE_OUTPUTS.GLADOSType)
        {
            Speeches.Add (Activator.CreateInstance (POSSIBLE_OUTPUTS.AllOptions[i]) as GLADOSVoice);                                       
        }    
    }                
}
```

Comment: I don't get what's the use of `k`

Comment: The second for loop is creating a certain amount of instances per available type. In this case, 5 each!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they all derive from `SentenceFactory` you can replace all the ifs and casts with just

```
Speeches.Add(Activator.CreateInstance (POSSIBLE_OUTPUTS.AllOptions[i]) as SentenceFactory);
```

Comment: That certainly cleans things up. From my lack of knowledge, I dont know if casting as a base type will remove all the extensions present in the derived instance. Do you think there will a problem there?

Comment: @SamuelJ No, it doesn't. The objects are always of the derived type, no matter how you cast them to parent types.