# Pass an array or list of different objects to a function for modification

Tags: c#, .net

Currently I am receiving an array of objects from a database.

```
object [] sqlResultData = DatabaseCall.Result();
```

This array of objects needs to be matched to class variables like this

```
CClassOfVars classVar = new CClassOfVars();
classVar.myProperty = sqlResultData[0];
classVar.myProperty1 = sqlResultData[1];
```

What i wish to do is pass the list of propertys on the class in order to a function and have the mapping from the object array occur automatically based on the order.

For example:

Method defined like this

```
FillData(object [] databaseValues, IList<object>())
```

Called like this

```
CClassOfVars classVar = new CClassOfVars();
object [] sqlResultData = DatabaseCall.Result();
FillData(sqlResultData, new List<object>(){classVar.myProperty,classVar.myProperty1});
```

The FillData function would hopefully type cast and set the values of myProperty and myProperty1 to the values in array locations of 0,1 etc...

Something like this

```
FillData(object [] databaseValues, IList<object> mapMe)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < mapMe.Count; i++)
     {
        mapMe[i] = CastToTheCorrectType(mapMe[i], databaseValues[i]);
     }
}
```

Cast to the correct type could look like this?? I took from here: [cast object with a Type variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005427/cast-object-with-a-type-variable)

```
 public T CastToTheCorrectType<T>(T hackToInferNeededType, object givenObject) where T : class
  {
     return givenObject as T;
  }
```

**How can i pass a list of different object types to all have there values modified and assigned within a different function?**

Comment: Have a look at [dapper](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/212274/A-Look-at-Dapper-NET) or entity framework, then you dont need such hacks

Answer (score 0):

The matter you asking about is dark and difficult to be implemented through just a function. There are frameworks out there dealing with [object relational mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). If it is an option, install and learn some OR/M. If not ... well,  there might be some dirty way.

You can use the JSON.NET library to do the heavy lifting for you. It's super easy to use and install through Nuget. My point is as follows.

1. Construct an anonymous object. Use the property names of the original object.
2. Fill it with the data from the object array. Spin a loop over the object array...
3. Serialize the anonymous object.
4. Deserialize the JSON string into the target type.
   At this point, JSON.NET will handle property mapping for you.
5. List item

E.g. if your target type is `Person` you might do this:

```
var x = new 
{
    FirstName = String.Empty,
    LastName = String.Empty
};

var persons = new List<Person>(sqlResultData.Length);

foreach (var record in sqlResultData)
{
    x.FirstName = record[0];
    x.LastName = record[1];

    var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)`
    var personX = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Person>(s);
    persons.Add(person);
}
```